# Как вынести построение DOM в отдельную функцию с настраиваемыми options?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dom

Есть выдача товара, выводятся допустим по 20 штук, при этом есть огромный фильтр и подгрузка по скроллу. Сейчас это 2 разных скрипта, но хотелось бы объединить в один и вынести построение DOM в отдельную функцию.

В каждом из вызовов есть 2 отличающихся друг от друга момента, при получении ответа, когда что-либо изменилось в фильтре шлю данные, получаю ответ и использую `$('.container').html(html);`, в то время как при подгрузке скроллом `$(html).appendTo('.container');`.

```
function scrollLoad() {
  var pages = 1;
  var load = true;

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if (load) {
      var $heightContainer = $('.container').height() - 500;
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > $blockBarContainer) {
        load = false;
        pages++;
        $.getJSON('/someURl/' + pages, function(data) {
          var items = data.items;
          if (items.length !== 0) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(items, function(key, val) {
              html += '<li class="item">' +
                '<div class="item-wrap">';
              html += val.someInfo +
                '</div>' +
                '</li>';
              $(html).appendTo('.container');
              html = '';
              load = true;
            });
          } else {
            // var html = '';
            load = false;
          }
        })
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Код для фильтра:

```
function filterLoad() {
  var ajaxTimeout = false,
    delayBeforeSend = '';

  var data = $('.filter').serialize();

  function sendForm() {
    $.getJSON('/someURl/', data, function(data) {
      var items = data.items;
      if (items.length !== 0) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(items, function(key, val) {
          html += '<li class="item">' +
            '<div class="item-wrap">';
          html += val.someInfo +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>';
          $('.container').html(html);
        });
      } else {
        var html = '';
      }
    })
  }
  if (ajaxTimeout) clearTimeout(ajaxTimeout);
  loadSubscriptions();
  ajaxTimeout = setTimeout(sendForm, delayBeforeSend);
}
```

Использую именно `getJSON()`, так как удобнее.

Вопрос в следующем: как вынести построение DOM в отдельную функцию, но при этом чтобы можно было указать options.

Задачи:

Не забыть о цикле который есть, а конкретно о `var items = data.items;`
А также настраиваемые `.append()` и `.html()`

P.S. Естественно, я не жду готового решения, просто подсказки в каком направлении копать.

Comment: о каких _options_ идет речь?

Comment: @Grundy настраиваемые для функции построения DOM

Comment: приведи пример, пока непонятно что тут имеется ввиду

Comment: `function createDomAfterAjax(){ /*do stuff*/ }

createDomAfterAjax({
method: append
});`

Comment: Не понял предыдущий комментарий. Как он относится к options? Для изменения своего вопроса используй кнопку [edit] под ним

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, вам не нужно так часто вставлять результаты в DOM. У меня получилось нечто такое:

```
var pages = 1;
var load = true;

function scrollLoad (){
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        if (load) {
            var $heightContainer = $('.container').height() - 500;
            if($(this).scrollTop() > $blockBarContainer) {
                load = false;
                pages++;
                getDataAndRender(pages, {}, 'append');
            }
        }
    });
}

function filterLoad() {
    var ajaxTimeout = false,
        delayBeforeSend = '';

    var data = $('.filter').serialize();

    getDataAndRender('', data, 'html');

    if (ajaxTimeout) clearTimeout(ajaxTimeout);
    loadSubscriptions();
    ajaxTimeout = setTimeout(sendForm, delayBeforeSend);
}

function getDataAndRender(page, requestData, action) {
    $.getJSON('/someURl/' + page, requestData, function(respondData){

        var items = respondData.items,
            html = '';

        if (items.length !== 0) {
            $.each(items, function(key, val){
                html += '<li class="item">' +
                    '<div class="item-wrap">' +
                        val.someInfo +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</li>';
            });
            if(action == 'append') {
                $('.container').append(html);
                pages = 1;
            } else {
                $('.container').html(html);
            }
            load = true;
        } else {
            load = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Как тогда быть c `+ page`, если листинг страниц нужен только при скролле, к запросу фильтра он отношения не имеет?

Comment: Ну так передали пустой `page` и не паритесь